# Symfony manyToOne nullable not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities linked with a ManyToOne relationship: Extra and GlobalExtra.The relationship is not mandatory, so that "Extra" may have a null global_extra_id.

The other relationship with the entity of Hotel works well but in this case the relationship is mandatory and if hotel_id is never null

YML Extra:

```
ByHours\HotelBundle\Entity\Extra:
type: entity
table: by_extras
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    hotelId:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        column: hotel_id
    globalExtraId:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        column: global_extra_id
    active:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        unsigned: false
        default: '1'
        column: active
    countable:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        unsigned: false
        default: '0'
        column: countable
    price:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 10
        scale: 2
        default: '0.00'
        column: price
    image:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        fixed: false
    deleted:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        unsigned: false
        default: '0'
        column: deleted
    useAmount:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        unsigned: false
        default: '1'
        column: use_amount
    created:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
    modified:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
manyToOne:
    hotel_extras:
        targetEntity: ByHours\HotelBundle\Entity\Hotel
        inversedBy: extras
        joinColumn:
          name: hotel_id
          referencedColumnName: id
    global_extras:
        targetEntity: ByHours\HotelBundle\Entity\GlobalExtra
        joinColumn:
          name: global_extra_id
          referencedColumnName: id
          nullable: true
oneToMany:
    extraSchedules:
      targetEntity: ByHours\HotelBundle\Entity\ExtraSchedule
      mappedBy: extra_schedules
    extraTranslations:
      targetEntity: ByHours\HotelBundle\Entity\ExtraTranslate
      mappedBy: extra_translations
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

YML GlobalExtra:

```
ByHours\HotelBundle\Entity\GlobalExtra:
type: entity
table: by_global_extras
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 255
        fixed: false
    price:
        type: decimal
        nullable: true
        precision: 10
        scale: 2
        default: '0.00'
        column: price
    image:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 255
        fixed: false
    countable:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
        unsigned: false
        default: '0'
        column: countable
    created:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
    modified:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And I always get the following error:

> [Mon Mar 14 October: 34: 48.931980 2016] [fcgid: warn] [pid 17064: 
>   139946383820544 tid] [client 10.0.2.2:54993] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP
>
> Warning:require(/opt/framework/Web/symfony/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__ByHoursHotelBundleEntityGlobalExtra.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>
> /var/www/Web/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 207

Yes I have cleared cache using:

```
php app / console cache: clear --no-warmup
```

and assigned permissions to the temporary folder

Comment: If you have not warmed up the cache from console, sf will try doing it on first request. Most likely your webserver/fpm runs from different user then you use to clear the cache. If that user does not have enough permissions to write to cache folder, you will see error like this. Please see "[Setting up permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup)" section of manual for typical solutions.

Comment: While I don't usually use YAML config to describe Entities (I much prefer annotations) you're configuration does not seem correct. You're talking about ManyToOne relations, but you're configuration does not reflect what is documented on the Doctrine website. It seems like your fields are basic integer fields and you're doing relations by hand. See more here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

With that in mind I think you're questions title is off - you have a cache/permission problem, not an entity relation one.

Comment: I tried to remove the entire cache folder "/opt" (in my case), I gave permission using "sudo chmod -R 777 /opt" and it worked!!!. Thanks!!